# Nuxt PWA - Are lifecycle hooks called on PWA open?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I have a installable PWA and the problem that my front-page doesn't reload content if the app is opened - It still shows the cached version.

Only if I trigger a manual refresh the `fetch()` hook is called.
Do the lifecycle hooks even get called if the app is opened or is there another way to implement such a behaviour?

Comment: Invalidating the cache is still the best approach IMO. Not sure how to do it tho.

Comment: Do you mean the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)? That should work just fine with PWAs.